# Long HTTP POST Response Time

Tags: http, web-applications, jboss

I have a web app that has some fairly hefty data processing on the backend. A current example workflow is:

1. User POSTS a form
2. Server receives form, starts processing
3. 2-4 minutes pass
4. The server responds

The reason i'm asking this is that initially a web proxy on the user side was killing idle POSTs after 2 minutes. The more I think about it the more this seemed like a reasonable default.

This leaves the question, should I increase the timeout and not fix the problem? Or is this bad practice? It is currently at 2-4 minutes but could easily get longer.  Should the application be responding with something rather than just leaving the connection open? If so other than completely redesigning the UI to be asynchronous submit/check back later what options are there?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if I were to submit a form and it would take that long, I would think something would have gone wrong and attempt to submit again.  I think that you should collect the data and give the user some sort of success message.  Then create another page that allows them to check on the status of the processing (if the user needs to get the results from that processing).

Comment: Yep absolutely I agree with this, however the counter argument is that this is primarily an internal app with trained users. To justify the redesign i think it would need to be a technical reason why this is wrong rather than a UX one.

Comment: What happens if the user closes out of the browser or accidentally resubmits?  How well does it handle multiple submissions at one time?  Will there be a revolt when the process starts taking 10 minutes to complete?